# How to save blob files in excel cells

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, oracle

I have table consist of column("file as pdf") which stores the bills.

my problem is i want to export that table to excel sheet.

is it possible?

So far i tried this..

```
 Dim xapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Workbook = xapp.Workbooks.Add
    Dim ws As Worksheet = wb.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Activate()

    'Fill header of the sheet----------------------------------

    For i As Integer = 1 To dgvcustomer.Columns.Count
        ws.Cells(1, i) = dgvcustomer.Columns(i - 1).HeaderText
    Next

    'End header------------------------------------------------

    Dim Dgrow, Dgcell, Dgcol As Integer
    Dgrow = 1
    Dgcell = 1

    'Fill Sheet -----------------------------------------------------------------------

    While (Dgrow <= dgvcustomer.Rows.Count)
        Dgcol = 1
        While (Dgcol <= ws.UsedRange.Columns().Count)
            ws.Cells(Dgrow + 1, Dgcol).value = dgvcustomer.Rows(Dgrow - 1).Cells(ws.Cells(1, Dgcol).value).Value
            Dgcol += 1
        End While
        Dgrow += 1
    End While

    'End fill sheet--------------------------------------------------------------------

    wb.SaveAs(dlgSaveFile.FileName)
    wb.Close()
    xapp.Quit()
```

This code works for non blob data type columns but for blob it raises exception.

[image: Exception image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Excel does not support storing data blobs in cells of worksheets.

You should probably export these PDFs each to individual files, and specify the file name in the exported worksheet.

Comment: None that are likely to meet your needs. (You might be able to save the whole table in a SQL dump file, for instance, but that's not a human-readable format.)